What is a good app to register how the keyboard is used in regards to understand repetitive strain injury (RSI) causes better?
I'm searching for a way to register all keys pressed and give me insights in how I use the keyboard. I type very fast, a lot and heavily use shortcuts during the day. I have some repetitive strain injury (RSI) like symptoms in my hands and fingers and would like to understand better which fingers I used the most, and how much.
Ideally, I would see some statistics into what hand and what fingers I use the most (derived from the keys pressed). How often specific keys or combinations are pressed, how fast et cetera.
I could not find any such app hence my question. Preferably FOSS and cross-platform but suggestions for paid options will do as well. I'm mostly interested in an app for Windows 11.

Welcome Bob!  Great question!  Do you have OS or price/gratis requirements.  If so, please add them to your question and tags.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

@AmazonDiesInDarkness thank you. Done.

There is WhatPulse.  It will do the heatpmap for the keyboard and more.

Track. Improve. Compete.
Analyze your productivity and activity using WhatPulse. Track time spent in applications, keyboard and mouse usage, and network traffic.

My RSI stems from the mouse, not the keyboard.  If it is your mouse hand that hurts more than try what I did.  I use the mouse with my right hand for half a day and use it with my left of the rest.  IT does not take long for the brain to adjust.

Thank you. Seems like a very good app. I will give it a try. I use a trackball mouse with my (main) right hand. Strangely I have more issues with my left hand, I expect heavy use of shortcuts is to blame. Which is another reason I want to track it.

There are some web based tools, so they will work for Windows.  You type online.  It may not be what you want, but its worth looking at them.

QMK Heatmap.  Although iot mentions QMK keyboard, it works with any.


What it is
This is a web-based tool to generate a pretty heatmap of your typing habits. As opposed to all the other available keyboard heatmap generators, this doesn’t merely analyse a static piece of text and overlays the letter frequency of said piece of text over a picture of the most basic row-stagger keyboard. This generator has full support for unprintable keys like backspace, modifier keys, caps lock, F-keys, arrow keys etc. Additionally, advanced QMK features such as layers, modtaps, layertaps, home row mods, leader keys, autoshift, and even combos are also supported.

. Heatmap Keyboard

Visualizing character distribution of texts on a keyboard while you're typing...

